# in Linux Uart(serial communication) can we change time gap between packets

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, uart

Using Rockpis i am implementing Uart(serial communication), made a configuration of 9600bps baudrate then transfering the data, other end using Docklight software capturing the data.
Here the time gap between two packets it is of 17Milliseconds at baudrate is 9600bps, is it possible to reduce that 17milliseconds to 10 milliseconds.
here i have attached image below.

Comment: It is probably the time for the application to prepare and write the next packet, regardless of the configuration or parameters of the serial communication function. Serial communication usually does not have such a function. You need to measure and detect which part of the application or system is actually taking the time, and then think about how to deal with it.

Comment: Switching to DMA mode may help.